# Show this operator is almost unitary

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I have the following exercise, for $x=\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n}\right), y=\left(y_{1}, \ldots, y_{n}\right) \in \mathbb{C}^{n}$ let $\langle x, y\rangle=\sum_{j=1}^{n} x_{j} \bar{y}_{j} .$ Suppose that $T$ is a linear operator on $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ such that $\langle x, y\rangle=0$ implies $\langle T x, T y\rangle=0 .$ Show $T=c S$ for some scalar $c$ and some unitary operator $S$.

Is easy to see that $T=cS$ fulfill the condition due to the fact that if $\langle x, y\rangle=0$ impling $\langle T x, T y\rangle=0 $ is almost an isometry. So intuitively is easy to see, but I am not sure how to prove it. Any ideas?

Comment: One approach is to note that if the condition holds, then $T^*T$ must be diagonal with respect to every orthonormal basis (where $T^*$ denotes the conjugate-transpose of $T$)

Comment: Another approach is this: suppose that $u,v$ are non-zero vectors for which $\|Tu\|/\|u\| \neq \|Tv\|/\|v\|$. Show that there exist vectors $x = c_1 u + c_2 v$ and $y = d_1 u + d_2 v$ for which $\langle x,y\rangle = 0$ but $\langle Tx, Ty \rangle \neq 0$